# Is there a name for a domestic company that uses a foreign (sounding) name?

Tags: british-english, names

Is there a (British Engligh) word to describe a company that uses a foreign word as it's name for marketing purposes? For example, Tableau is an American data visualisation company and tableau is French for picture. Or Wagamama is a British restaurant that sells Japanese food and wagamama is Japanese for self-indulgence.

this has caused much debate in the office.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't, and I can't see why there should be. *Pret a Manger* is a very well-known example, but it's just a business with a funny-sounding name (unless you know some French).

Comment: Given that [***exotic***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exotic) is (primarily) defined as *Originating in or characteristic of **a distant foreign country***, I think you could reasonably use ***exotically-named***. But it's also commonly used with the sense of *Attractive or striking because **colourful or out of the ordinary***, so not everyone would understand the "foreign" implication there. I can't find any instances on Google, but the nonce word ***exotonymic*** would certainly work for me to very specifically convey *named by using a foreign (or unusual) "word"*.

Comment: ...[***Exoticism**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/exoticism) is the quality of seeming unusual or interesting, usually because of associations with a distant country.*

Comment: See this wikipdeia [Häagen-Dazs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Häagen-Dazs#Origin_of_brand_name) entry, which mentions *foreign branding strategies*.

Comment: *Pretentious* is the one I use. Like for *Pret-à-manquer* ...

Comment: I don't know, but I have a word for when I get charged import beer prices for a Yuengling.

Comment: FWIW "Tableau" has been an English word for at least 350 years. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tableau

Comment: Since it's marketing purpose where names are fashionable depending on the time  I would call it an "in vogue" name. Currently names that are short foreign sounding  or mashup words have become fashionable due to the smartphone app culture where apps have short made up or foreign language origin.

Comment: "Tableau" seem like a poor example. It may be of French origin, but I think it has thoroughly entered the English lexicon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't find a single word, but Wikipedia defines the marketing strategy of [foreign branding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_branding) as assigning:

> foreign or foreign-sounding brand names for companies, products, and services

with the aim of

> trying to make customers believe that the company and/or its products originate from a more favourable country than they actually do

Perhaps you could refer to the habit as *faux-foreign* branding?

Comment: Good find, StuartLC!